# DTM: Is Delay Link Activation of 250ms really necessary?

Tags: adobe-analytics, adobe-dtm

It is explained or implied somewhere in the DTM documentation, that the *Delay Link Activation* option is there so that the Analytics call can be made before the current page unloads.

Is this really necessary? It seems to assume that the Analytics call must be done asynchronously, in a race against the clock. Why isn't the Analytics call made synchronously within the click event handler? That would be generally much faster than 250ms, and would eliminate a race condition.